# visual layout editor does not allow drag&drop

Tags: android-studio

I'am a newby in android studio and learning a lot, but now have a problem where i cannot seem to find the answer to.
In android studio you can visualy drag&drop your screen.
I have seen it can do al lot (although you sometimes need the xml) but for me it is not working at all.
I mean i cannot drag&drop any widgets on the screen at all.

- Tried changing the theme: no help (really tried a lot of them)
- Tried a complete new project: same story
- Tried other APK verion: same story
- Tried Invalidatd caches / restart: no help

Even with a new project (EmptyActivity) it add's a android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView and then gives error's on that
(Failed to find style 'coordinatorLayoutStyle' in current theme).

It also gives an error on layout_height/layout_with not being there. But they are there for each widget.

Please do not missunderstand: when i execute the project i runs just fine (both on phone and emulator) but the visual builder for the screen.....:-(

Does somebody knows how to solve this.
If more info is needed please ask.

Any help is more than welcome.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that could be causing this:

- Your caches could be messed up. Try going to
  `File` > `Invalidate Caches / Restart ...` (I know that you already tried this, but posting for future views.)
- Also, make sure that you don't have `Drag-n-Drop with ALT pressed only` checked in your Settings (`Appearance & Behavior - Appearance`).
- Finally, in a default project created in Android Studio, there are two XML files created for each layout. For example, `content_main.xml` is embedded within `activity_main.xml`. Make sure that you are using `content_main.xml` for your design work.

Comment: thanks for your answer shagberg.
The "Drag-n-Drop with ALT pressed only" is disabled. so that is not it.
As for the content_main/activity_main, yes i know this is the case. But even with a 'empty activity' (you only have a activity_main.xml i have the problem

Answer (score 0):

In the end i fixed it by changing the SDK version in de gradle file.
still do not understand why it was wrong as studio genereded it that way but now it works so.... for me: case closed.